# Compiling a OSGi bundle with registered hook for Liferay

Tags: java, maven, liferay, liferay-7, wab

I am trying to make configurable logging application for Liferay 7.4.3 with Apache Maven. I have no problem making the app configurable using [this approach](https://learn.liferay.com/w/dxp/building-applications/core-frameworks/configuration-framework/setting-and-accessing-configurations), when compiling the project as a OSGi bundle (using bnd-maven-plugin).

However I need to register the hook in the webapp/WEB-INF/liferay-hook.xml such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hook PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Hook 7.1.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-hook_7_1_0.dtd">

<hook>
    <servlet-filter>
        <servlet-filter-name>My Hook</servlet-filter-name>
        <servlet-filter-impl>MyHook</servlet-filter-impl>
    </servlet-filter>
    <servlet-filter-mapping>
        <servlet-filter-name>My Hook</servlet-filter-name>
        <before-filter>SSO Open SSO Filter</before-filter>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-filter-mapping>
</hook>
```

Is there a way to combine both hook and a configurable app into single application? i.e. Compiling a OSGi bundle in such a way that would contain hook registration in webapp/WEB-INF/liferay-hook.xml?

I have a working implementation of application with hook using that approach, however it is compiled as a WAR to include the WEB-INF folder.

I tried compiling the app as a WAB using both bnd-maven-plugin and maven-bundle-plugin to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for the 6.x style hooks. You can implement a servlet filter following [this example](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/blob/master/liferay-workspace/extensions/servlet-filter/src/main/java/com/liferay/blade/samples/servletfilter/BladeServletFilter.java):

```
@Component(
        immediate = true,
        property = {

// To figure out valid values for before-filter, look up Liferay's
// WEB-INF/liferay-web.xml

                "before-filter=Auto Login Filter",
                "dispatcher=REQUEST",
//              "dispatcher=FORWARD",
//              "dispatcher=ASYNC",
//              "dispatcher=ERROR",
//              "dispatcher=INCLUDE",
                "servlet-context-name=",

                // Pick your own unique filter name! Make sure to pick a
                // different one for every filter you write - see LPS-107575

                "servlet-filter-name=Blade Servlet Filter",
                "url-pattern=/web/*",
                "url-pattern=/change/me"
        },
        service = Filter.class
)
public class BladeServletFilter extends BaseFilter {

    @Override
    protected Log getLog() {
        return _log;
    }

    @Override
    protected void processFilter(
            HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws Exception {

        // implement your own logic here
        // determine if you shortcut, or continue in the filter chain

        httpServletResponse.addHeader(
            "X-Blade-Servlet-Filter", httpServletRequest.getRequestURI());

        processFilter(
            BladeServletFilter.class.getName(), httpServletRequest,
            httpServletResponse, filterChain);
    }

    private static final Log _log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(
        BladeServletFilter.class);

}
```